# display data with ngFor trigger after click any button why?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

I use angular at the frontend and .net-core at the backend. I fetch data very well. But it only display after click any button(for example the app-language-selector dropdown). When I click dropdown button page loads. I follow my code with breakpoints;

ngOnInit works well when the route comes ngOnInit and the loadDevices() method works and gets deviceList from db. But display nothing?. When I press any button ngfor triggered and display data.

Same things at the pagination and delete method too. ts file works but html file need a button trigger. Any Idea?

html :

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
    
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <div class="header-logo">
                  <a routerLink="/">
                      <img style="width: 60px; height: 60px; align-items: center;" alt="Logo"
                          src="logoPath" />
                  </a>
              </div>
    
    
              <div class="pull-right">
                  <app-language-selector></app-language-selector>
                  <--- App language selector --->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let device of devices">
        <div class="card card-custom listCard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
              <div class="row">
                <span class="definationTitle">
                  Name : &nbsp;
                </span>
                <span>
                  {{device.name}}
                </span>
              </div>
            <--- I have another divs for brand, explanation, model etc --->
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<--- And pagination here --->
```

.ts file;

```
export class DeviceListComponent implements OnInit {

  public devices : deviceListModel[] = [];
  pagination : Pagination;
  pageNumber = 1;
  pageSize = 5;
  isLoaded = false;
  //public deviceList : deviceListModel[] = [];

  constructor(private service : DeviceService, private toastr: ToastrService, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadDevices();
    //this.getDeviceList();
  }

  loadDevices() {
    this.service.getDevices(this.pageNumber, this.pageSize).subscribe(res => {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.devices= res.result;
      this.pagination = res.pagination;
    })
  }

  deleteDevice(device){
    this.service.deleteDevice(device.id).subscribe( res => {
      if(!res.hasError)
      {
        this.toastr.success("Success",{
          positionClass: "toast-top-center",
        });
        this.loadDevices();
      }else{
        this.toastr.error(res.message, "Error",{
          positionClass: "toast-top-center",
        });
      }
    })
  }

  pageChanged(event:any){
    this.pageNumber = event.page;
    this.loadDevices();
  }

  getDeviceList() {
    this.service.getDeviceList().subscribe(res => {
      this.devices = res;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no condition to hide elements? Don't see any error as such in the code

Comment: @MirentafazAli There is no condition. The problem is not about pagination also, I tested. This is really interesting problem. Both ts and html works well but ngFor trigger automatically after click any button

Comment: Okay in that case a working demo would be very helpful.